# CSS working fine in firefox but not displaying properly on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the desired effect on firefox, which is to display like this:

```
   _________
  | title   |__________________
  |                            | 
  |                            |  
  |                            |
  |  content here              |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |                            |
   ____________________________
```

but it simply displays a deformed rectangle in IE

What could be the possible issues?

EDIT:

This is the border of a webpage. The title is on the smaller box on top of the bigger one.

Comment: Until you show the CSS and HTML that builds the tabbed rectangle, it's a pretty useless question.

Comment: Ok I will give the code... don't close

Comment: hahahahahahahahahaha - story of my life. IE, not work? since when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use tables for this purpose. Use div instead.

Use tables for... well.. tabular data :)

It's also not working in Chrome. I find it strange that it even works in FF :P

Now for the answer:

One thing I noticed is you have an td with colspan 0.

You also set you tabs col (first row) to a specific width. That's why the col underneath it is also that width.

Change:

```
<td class="Container" colspan="0">
```

To:

```
<td class="Container" colspan="2">
```

EDIT:

Check out fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/htFXG/

I've improved your code so that it is: better readable, works in 'all' browsers, just better ;)

Comment: wow! thanks for the insight... it now works in IE but I need to reduce the top box size..

Comment: What top box? The tab? And in which direction do you need to reduce it's size?

Comment: yeah the tab.... It needs to look like it does in firefox...

Comment: You now have `<td class="Container" colspan="7">` in stead of `<td class="Container" colspan="2">` :)

Comment: yeah I tried changing it in the hope that it decreases the size of the tab

Comment: One moment let me create a fiddle for you with the way I would implement this.

Comment: Check out the fiddle I've created. This should work in all modern browsers... and IE. http://jsfiddle.net/htFXG/